k8s oomkilled How do I generate dump files
In k8s java project oom is killed by k8s in advance can not generate dump file, is there a solution
Do not know how to configure dump generation. If the configuration does not take effect. I want to generate dump files for analysis before killing the java project~

It's the OS that kills Java process, not k8s. JVM has no way to intercept or handle OOM killer, therefore, it cannot generate dump files. What you can do is to monitor memory usage periodically, and once it reaches certain threshold, generate a dump with jcmd.


JVM flags for automatic heap dump:
The flags -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/dump.hprof configure the JVM to automatically generate a heap dump file (dump.hprof) whenever an OutOfMemoryError occurs within the application.
Remember to replace /path/to/dump.hprof with a directory inside the container that has write permissions for the Java process.
Persistent volume for dump files:
Mounting a persistent volume to the container provides a dedicated storage location for the generated heap dump file dump.hprof.
This ensures the file persists even if the pod gets restarted or killed due to OOM. This way, you can access the dump file for later analysis even after the application crashes.


The question is not about OutOfMemoryError thrown by the JVM, but rather about OS-level OOM killer.
